# How to Navigate from remote microfrontend app to host app's route

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, micro-frontend

I'm trying to Implement Cam Jackson’s micro-frontend applications, so far I'm able to create 3 following react application:

1. parent app
2. child1 app
3. child2 app

[blog reference](https://betterprogramming.pub/5-steps-to-turn-a-random-react-application-into-a-micro-frontend-946718c147e7)

The problem that I'm facing is with the routing.
parent app routes:

```
const Child1 = ({ history }) => (
  <MicroFrontend history={history} host={childapp1} name="child1" />
);

const Child2 = ({ history }) => (
  <MicroFrontend history={history} host={childapp2} name="child2" />
);

const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
  <Account>
    <React.Fragment>
    <ReactNotifications />
      <AppHeader />
      <Routes>
      <Route exact path="/" element={<Signin/>} />
        <Route exact path="/about" element={<About/>} />
        <Route exact path="/child1/*" element={<Child1/>} />
        <Route exact path="/child2/*" element={<Child2/>} />
      </Routes>
    </React.Fragment>
    </Account>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Child app1 routes:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Account>
    <React.Fragment>
    <ReactNotifications />
      <Routes>
      <Route path='child1' element={<ProtectedRoute><Home/></ProtectedRoute>}/>
        <Route
          path="child1/dashboard"
          element={
            <ProtectedRoute>
              <Dashboard/>
            </ProtectedRoute>
          }
        />
        <Route path="child1/forbidden" element={<ForbiddenPage/>}
        />
      </Routes>
    </React.Fragment>
    </Account>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

So far all right, When i try to navigate from child1/any-route to '/' which is a signin route in parent. it tries to search for a component which is at '/' in the child app1 routes which seems to be a expected behaviour, what i want to understand is how can i navigate from childapp1's component to parent app's signin route.

i tried to navigate using useNavigate hook on token expiry by following code:

In child app1

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ children }) => {
    const { authData } = useAuth()
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    
    console.log(authData, 'authData');

    if (authData.isAuthenticated && authData.expiryTime > Date.now()) {
        return children
    }
    else{
        navigate('/')
    }
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

expected workflow is:
`parent app's signin -> childapp1/home -> authToken expires -> navigate to parent app's signin`

update:
MicroFrontend.js

```
import React from 'react';

class MicroFrontend extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { name, host, document } = this.props;
    const scriptId = `micro-frontend-script-${name}`;

    if (document.getElementById(scriptId)) {
      this.renderMicroFrontend();
      return;
    }
    // if (document.getElementById(styleId)) {
    //   this.renderMicroFrontend();
    //   return;
    // }
    var parentUrl = `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.href.split('/')[2]}`
    if (name === 'child1'){
      fetch(`${parentUrl}/child1/asset-manifest.json`,{
        method: "GET",
      })
        .then(res =>res.json())
        .then(manifest => {
          console.log(manifest, 'manifest');
          const script = document.createElement('script');
          const linkforCSSfile = document.createElement("link")
  
          linkforCSSfile.href = `${parentUrl}/child1${manifest['files']['main.css']}`
          linkforCSSfile.type = 'text/css'
          linkforCSSfile.rel = 'stylesheet'
  
          script.id = scriptId;
          script.crossOrigin = '';
          script.src = `${parentUrl}/child1${manifest['files']['main.js']}`;
          script.onload = this.renderMicroFrontend;
  
          document.head.appendChild(script);
          document.head.appendChild(linkforCSSfile)
        })
    }
    else{

      fetch(`${parentUrl}/child2/asset-manifest.json`,{
        method: "GET",
      })
        .then(res =>res.json())
        .then(manifest => {
          console.log(manifest, 'manifest');
          const script = document.createElement('script');
          const linkforCSSfile = document.createElement("link")
  
          linkforCSSfile.href = `${parentUrl}/child2${manifest['files']['main.css']}`
          linkforCSSfile.type = 'text/css'
          linkforCSSfile.rel = 'stylesheet'
  
          script.id = scriptId;
          script.crossOrigin = '';
          script.src = `${parentUrl}/child2${manifest['files']['main.js']}`;
          script.onload = this.renderMicroFrontend;
  
          document.head.appendChild(script);
          document.head.appendChild(linkforCSSfile)
    })
  }
    
      
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    const { name, window } = this.props;

    window[`unmount${name}`]?.(`${name}-container`);
  }

  renderMicroFrontend = () => {
    const { name, window, history } = this.props;
    console.log(history);

    window[`render${name}`]?.(`${name}-container`, history);
  };

  render() {
    return <main id={`${this.props.name}-container`} />;
  }
}

MicroFrontend.defaultProps = {
  document,
  window,
};

export default MicroFrontend;
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is `history` that is passed to the children route components? Do all the app's routers share a common history object reference? The "nested" routers should probably have a specified `basename` prop to match where they are located relative to the parent app/router.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I have refered the the above mentioned blog code for my micro-frontend and it seems like i should not be passing history since i am using react-router-dom 6.14.1 where useHistory is replaced with useNavigate, and it also not possible to use useNavigate hook in my MicroFrontend class based component . however as you have pointed out, it is necessary to pass history to each child application. but can you help me figure out how can i achieve this. 
I have updated the question with MicroFrontend.js file for more context.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You ***might*** be able to get by with using the [`HistoryRouter`](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/39ab0a8ee1873a307faee0f58ce0865e25caf619/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx#L441-L491) with an instantiated `BrowserHistory` object in lieu of the `BrowserRouter` (*which instantiates an internal `history` reference of its own*). This method *does* require your project to include `history@5` as a project dependency.

```
npm install --save history@5
```

Example:

```js
import {
  unstable_HistoryRouter as HistoryRouter,
  Routes,
  Route
} from 'react-router-dom';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

const history = createBrowserHistory();

const App = () => (
  <HistoryRouter history={history}>
    <Account>
      <ReactNotifications />
      <AppHeader />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Signin />} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
        <Route
          path="/child1/*"
          element={(
            <MicroFrontend
              history={history}
              host={childapp1}
              name="child1"
            />
          )}
        />
        <Route
          path="/child2/*"
          element={(
            <MicroFrontend
              history={history}
              host={childapp2}
              name="child2"
            />
          )}
        />
      </Routes>
    </Account>
  </HistoryRouter>
);
```

Then similarly both children apps would import the `HistoryRouter` and pass the passed `history` object as a prop so they all reference the same history.